# How can I know from inside a pytest hook if pytest-xdist is enabled?

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-xdist

I want to write a `pytest` session finish hook that is aware if the xdist plugin has been activated (for example if the `-n` option has been passed). Is there an official / stable way to do this ? I found a way to identify if this is a xdist worker, but not to disambiguate between the xdist master and the 'main' pytest process when xdist is deactivated.

```
def pytest_sessionfinish(session):
    try:
        pytest_worker_id = session.config.slaveinput['slaveid']
    except AttributeError:
        # TODO disambiguate: are we the xdist master node or the "main" pytest node with xdist deactivated?
        ...
```

Note: this is to get rid of the try/except in this [conftest.py example](https://smarie.github.io/python-pytest-harvest/#pytest-x-dist)

Thanks in advance !
Kind regards

Comment: IIRC the master node is the main process, so you can't distinguish between them. As for the `xdist` "activation" - there's no such state for a plugin. If the plugin is installed, it will be registered and all its hooks will be executed. You can check whether `xdist` is installed though - e.g. via `config.pluginmanager.getplugin("xdist") is not None`.

Comment: Thanks ! I was afraid of this answer :)  but if that's the only way, fair enough.

Comment: pytest-xdist sets PYTEST_XDIST_WORKER_COUNT and PYTEST_XDIST_WORKER env var for all the worker processes. You can use those to find whether xdist is activated or not. 
More info in their repo: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-xdist

Comment: Thanks SilentGuy, this is a valuable addition.